# how to autowire in spring for test classes?

Tags: spring, testing

I am making some test for my classes in spring.

I am making the mockups and all, but I want to include certain services, I was wondering if there is any annotation to make this `@autowire` for test cases.

I checked for the @contextConfiguration but I dont know if is the proper one.

Thanks

Comment: Please show an example of what you're trying to do. For unit tests, constructor injection will let you easily use the ordinary mocks you use (Mockito, Spock) without needing Spring at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a skeleton of how your test class should look like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "<< YOURTRANSACTIONMANAGER >>", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class ServiceTest {

    //The name of your resource/service should be the same as defined in your bean definition
    @Resource
    private YourService service;

    @Test
    public void testYourService() {
        //Your Test code for eg.
        Object returned = service.doStuff();
        Assert.assertNotNull(returned);
    }


    public YourService getService() {
        return service;
    }


    public void setService(YourService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

}
```

For further reading you can refer this [Spring unit testing](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html)